# My doughnut shadow is fine in the viewport, but floating in render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

This is what my donut looks like in the viewport:
[image]
the shadow is fine and placed correctly. but when I make a image render, the shadow is misplaced, and it makes it look like my donut is floating like this:
[image]
I'm using the Eevee engine for this render, and I have no idea why it's looking so weird.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please share your blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to paste the link into your question.

Comment: looks like the problem was solved, anyway I'm having trouble uploading the file, if it happens again, I'll try again.